# Replace val in df with boolean indexing - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to replace a value in a pandas col using logical operator `&`. Using below, where `Label == A` and `Value is == np.nan`, I want to replace Value with `X`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({      
    'Time' : [1,1,2,2,3,3],    
    'Label' : ['A','B','A','B','A','B'],
    'x' : [-2.0,-1.0,-1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0],
    'y' : [-2.0,-1.0,-2.0,-1.0,-2.0,-1.0],    
    'Value' : [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,'Y',np.nan],          
   })

df.loc[(df['Label'] == 'A') & (df['Value'] == np.nan), 'Value'] = 'X'
```

intended output:

```
   Time Label    x    y Value
0     1     A -2.0 -2.0     X
1     1     B -1.0 -1.0   NaN
2     2     A -1.0 -2.0     X
3     2     B  0.0 -1.0   NaN
4     3     A  0.0 -2.0     Y
5     3     B  1.0 -1.0   NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `isna`

The point of `np.nan` is that it is ***N***ot ***A*** ***N***umber.  If you treat it like one, you get `False`.  It isn't even equal to itself, by design.

Instead use Pandas `isna`/`notna` or `isnull`/`notnull`

```
df.loc[(df['Label'] == 'A') & (df['Value'].isna()), 'Value'] = 'X'
```

Then you have

df

```
   Time Label    x    y Value
0     1     A -2.0 -2.0     X
1     1     B -1.0 -1.0   NaN
2     2     A -1.0 -2.0     X
3     2     B  0.0 -1.0   NaN
4     3     A  0.0 -2.0     Y
5     3     B  1.0 -1.0   NaN
```